# Print more elements through jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using a jquery script to print a form on webpage which uploads multiple images through upload.php and show progress bar. However I am trying to pass one more hidden value to upload.php but unable to do so. I tried to add

```
<input name='id' type='hidden' value='test' />
```

tag in this jquery script and on upload.php I tried to call it by $_POST['id'] but It's not working.

Any help is appreciated.

I am using this script
http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-upload-multiple-images-jquery-ajax-using-php_453.html

it has a jquery file that basically prints a form through jquery which allows multiple file upload.

Comment: Can you share with us the full code, not the minified version?

Comment: Sure, I have modified my question.

Comment: I don't think you can do it, since the script send the images only, not a form. So the hidden input will not sent to the server. I afraid you need to edit the plugin script so it will add the option to add data to the ajax request.

Comment: @Jan D You are awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add further parameters, such as an ID, by extending the target URL for upload. This does not allow user input, but since you wanted to use a hidden field, that should not concern you.

In the settings, `url: "upload.php",` could be extended to `url: "upload.php?id=<?php echo $some_id; ?>",`, thus assigning the value of `$some_id` to the parameter `id`.

You can then retrieve the value via `$_GET['id']`.